# How do you search questions for a tag on multiple (SO-SU-SF...) sites?

Tags: discussion, tags, search, stack-exchange, tabs

**Problem:**

If you are interesting in following any questions on, say (for instance), 'authentication', you can just open a new tab in your browser.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication (more than 800 questions)

Then you realize that there are interesting questions as well on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/authentication), or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/authentication) (3 questions), even on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authentication)!

That means opening 3 or 4 tabs (just for one topic).

If you follow actively 2 or 3 tags (in separate tabs, without using 'or' operator, in order to avoid having sorting through each list in order to not miss a question for a particular tag), and if those tags are relevant for 2 or more SO-family sites... you end up with a lot of opened tabs.

**Question:**

1/ Would it be possible, when asking for questions tagged xxx, to be able to requests results from other SO-family sites? For example:
(and the following is by no mean a 'solution', just a proposition to illustrate how to achieve the end-result)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication?sites=sf and su
```

would display questions from SO and SF and SU, in my current SO page.
(Hopefully, color-scheme associated with each questions, or an dedicated icon, could help pinpoint which site they come from, but actually, when you are interested in a topic, you do not really care *at first* where it has been published)

2/ If that is not possible (too complex, or too confusing for the user), what would be your suggestion for that kind of "question monitoring on multiple sites"? (except opening a gazillion of tabs ;) )

---

If that issue makes sense, I will add the 'feature-request' tag on it.
I am just looking for some feedbacks first (since there could very well be a much simpler solution to this).

---

I did some tests with Google:

- the results does not appear to follow a "most recent" order (which is what you want if you want to actively participate in the tags you are following)
- Google does not appear to support multiple "[Search within a specific website](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861)" (site:).
  Perhaps the ["Google Custom Search" API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/annotations.html) can help.

Regarding RSS, I am not sure the "refresh" rate of those feeds is quick enough for question monitoring (when you want to see at spot if a new question exists): a refresh in a browser directly query SO, but a refresh in an RSS aggregators would only display what has been published, or worse, what has been cached by the aggregator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible through the magic of filters!

[Here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/25892/demo-filter) I have set up an example filter to browse all questions from gaming.SE, Programmers.SE, and AskUbuntu.com.

It can also filter by tags, so it would be trivial to make a filter that displays all (and only!) the questions tagged [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication) on MSO, SO, SF, and SU.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just do a google search, scoped to..

stackoverflow.com/tags/tagname
serverfault.com/tags/tagname
superuser.com/tags/tagname

(note that `/tags/` is a synonym for `/questions/tagged/` although I had to fight Jarrod on this because he has this thing for URL route 'purity')

edit: alternately, I'm sure there are services out there which will combine RSS feeds -- you could combine the RSS feeds for that tag on all three sites.

Comment: I drank too much of the RESTFUL kool-aid.. I mean, I plead the 5th!

Comment: I am not sure Google could return the most recent question first (which is what you are after when "monitoring" a tag). I will try some Google search to see if it does solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For tag monitoring across sites, I'd just use RSS. You can get RSS feeds of a particular tag, so just use one for each site. (Some aggregators/other things have ways of treating more than one feed as a single feed).

Comment: I believe RSS feeds are not updated "quickly" enough to be effective (correct me if I am wrong). By the time you detect a new question, it is often too late to contribute in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare that I want to search the same tag on multiple sites; largely by definition I expect there to be a good difference in the content of each, and I'd only search on the most appropriate site (am I interested in server configuration? programming concerns? or the end-user's experience?). If the **same** content is on each, something is probably wrong...

Other than that... [google](http://www.google.com) ;-p

Comment: I do not believe that a tag present on multiple site means "duplicate content"; that said, your "very rare that I want to search the same tag on multiple sites" could be the definitive answer: if I am the only one having this issue, it is not useful for the community ;)

Answer (score 0):

Google or RSS do not answer my request.

I need a native search able to give me *at spot* across SO sites and right now, I have no choice but to open n windows for searching n site.

Comment: @John: what other answer do you want me to accept, then?

Comment: None? No-one is forcing you!

Comment: @John: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/ : Gotta have those 100% accept rate (and this question is closed, so no new answer to expect). Silly, I know, but if it is the game they want to play, I will play along...

Comment: You are playing it wrong!

Comment: @John: I agree. But in this instance... who cares?

Comment: Point            taken!